# How do i manage content workflow for hexo site?

Tags: github, jekyll, ejs, static-site, hexo

I've used static site generators like jekyll and had it hosted through github pages just fine using prose.io as a content management system.

I decided I wanted to go with a site using Hexo static site generator, but I cannot seem to figure out a good workflow for publishing content.

To my understanding this is the following in how I'd have to do it:

1. write *.md text file
2. `hexo generate`
3. (optional) `hexo serve` (to see local content)
4. `hexo deploy` (to publish the public content to whatever site using config.yml). Can publish on amazon S3, github pages, etc

Is there another workflow other than this?

the way I've been doing it before with jekyll+github pages is simply

1. go to prose.io
2. Write content
3. save (which publishes ocntent)

Ideally I'd like to use hexo+github pages the same way I do with jekyll+github pages.

Basically, can github generate static files automatically like it does with jekyll / ruby packages?

Answer (score 1):

I figured out my own answer and posted it on my blog

http://www.tangycode.com/Quick-Start-Guide-To-Hexo-Install/

It covers everything you need to know on how to set up a hexo blog site and manage content workflows

Comment: the link you posted is broken

Answer (score 1):

One approach I am trying myself:

- [prose.io](http://prose.io) or similar to write and save on github repository
- [travis-ci.org](https://travis-ci.org) to build hexo site and deploy

This is how it works:

1. Edit document on your editor of love
2. Commit it to your repository
3. [travis-ci.org](https://travis-ci.org) detects the commit and start working

My [.travis.yml](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jrbenito/benito.com.br/development/.travis.yml) do (among few other things) the follow:

- npm  install hexo-cli
- npm install grunt-cli
- npm install inside site´s repository (hexo plugins and dependecies)
- hexo generate
- grunt deploy-production
- hexo deploy (I use this to have a historic of the site stored in the repo itself)

If your editor of choice can direct commit to github repository your have exact same experience you had with Jekyll on GH pages. The advantage here is that you can use third-part plugin what GH pages avoid.

Comment: I did not used prose.io yet, I am commiting by hand but I will introduce it on top of my write workflow soon.

Comment: I haven't really used .travis-ci before, although I hear a lot about it. How does this compare to hosting static files on github though?

Comment: Well, travis is meant for test builds in continuous integration. In this case we are building the static web site. Think travis like your own machine development environment. What you execute on your machine you execute there, so after `hexo generate` you deploy right? Where do you deploy (GH, AWS, ...) is your business. So you can "commit" generated files back to you github pages repository and still use gh pages to host your site. In my case I host it on aws-s3+cloudfront but the solution is agnostic, you just need the plugin to deploy or write some script. Travis is actually a ubuntu docker

Comment: ![](http://i.imgur.com/jv2pY1a.png) am i understanding this correctly in terms of hexo workflow  + travis?

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can use [INSTANT](https://instant.cm), which is a content management tool that you can use on any static website. You just install their javascript and can directly edit content in your website (without any admin dashboard). It saves and serves the content from the client. Pretty neat.

Comment: this sounds really interesting I'll look into it thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use a hosting provider like [Netlify](http://netlify.com) in combination with a headless CMS, for example [Headless](http://www.headless.rest) (full disclore: I created it).

Netlify can do the build process for you and during that build process, it can fetch content from a headless CMS. Whenever you update content in the CMS, then Netlify does a rebuild.

Then you have your website on the Netlify CDN, a real CMS for your content management and you never need to dive in your code or github files. And that's all for free.